# weird behaviour after installing nvidia 361 driver

Tags: nvidia

I am using Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS 32 bit running linux kernel 4.4.0-36-generic on our embedded hardware.
After installing nvidia driver 361 from the repos, the system has started to behave weirdly.

First of all, the system would not boot up after the driver install and after a while of black screen would go into suspend state.I saw this in the syslog that the system was going into suspend state.

So to fix this, I added `acpi=off` in the grub command line and I was able to boot into my system.

After booting into the system, I am finding that it is behaving weirdly. sometimes when I open a new terminal it will not get any keyboard input, like keyboard is not attached. Other times, while typing I will see multiple key strokes in editor or command prompt even when the key is pressed once.

Also, sometimes the graphics of our gaming application will also look as if they are super fast.

this happens every few seconds(20-30).

Before installing nvidia 361 driver, everything worked fine.

so it got to be something with the driver installation.

Anyone facing similar issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updating to nvidia driver 367.44 resolves this problem.